# Define Internal and external vs Essence and illusion

Tags: philosophy-of-religion

In Buddhism, external reality is an illusion
and internal reality is an essence.

Luke 17, 21. Neither shall they say: Behold here, or behold there. For lo, the kingdom of God is within you.

How do we define the internal reality? As a psychological reality? Collective Unconscious?
Or souls' world?

I'm interested in defining (essence, illusion) and (internal, external).

Is my reality versus your reality merely "our" *conventional* reality?

Comment: This is a very broad question --are you looking for a Buddhist answer?  A Christian answer?  Some reason to assume that both traditions are talking about the same thing?

Comment: When you say "How [do] we define internal reality?" who is "we" in the sentence? Some would deny that there is such a thing as "internal reality" different than just "reality."

Comment: How is it possible for us to define reality? Real for me = real for you? Is a dream [external] reality?

Comment: Confusion among:
point of view, opinion, referential, or absolute reality.